# How to check database status using xquery?

Tags: marklogic

Is there any way to check database status , i.e whether it is in error/unavailable state on not using xquery..? 
I have done this so far.. but no luck

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace db = "model:database";
import module namespace x = "http://ns.dscape.org/2010/dxc/xml" at "/lib/dxc/xml/xml.xqy";
declare variable $databases := x:strip-namespaces( xdmp:read-cluster-config-file("databases.xml")/* );

for $db-id in xdmp:databases()
   let $db-status := $databases /database [database-name = $db-id] /(@*,*)
   return  $db-status*
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try REST available functions to get Database detail

```
http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/{$DbName}?view=status.
```

For more information please go through URL https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management/databases

Answer (score 2):

If you have the right privileges, you can use the administrative API:

```
xdmp:forest-status(xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database("databasename")))
```

Comment: But that will give me forest status only... I am looking for database status only .. :)